# CSS - Centre overflowing table cell content on it's parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm designing a site using Bootstrap and have got a large table with many columns, resulting in horizontal overflow. I've just added rows which stretch the full width of the table to group the data by month, with a centre aligned `<p>` tag indicating the month.  However, since the table overflows so far on most screens, the centre alignment displaces the text way off to the right, and at times, off-screen.
[image: Table]

(you can see my grey-filled full-width row with the text displaced right).

I've searched already a fair bit and have found some solutions for centre aligning a `<div>` with it's parent container using `flex`, but I've been unable to get this working within a table.

Does anyone know of a way of centre aligning my text with a parent container (say, the Bootstrap card the table is placed on).  I'd like it to appear in the centre of the viewable display so that it looks more natural to the user.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

**Edit**
I should have clarified, by positioning the text in the middle of the viewable screen, I was hoping that as the user scrolled horizontally, the text would remain in the middle of the screen.  I might be asking for too much here, just thought some of you CSS whizzes might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: how about using `padding-left: 50vw` rule ?

Comment: @RapSherlock that's a good start, I was hoping that the text might remain centre aligned reference the parent container even when the user scrolls horizontally.  I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: you can doing it with sticky rule, wait i'll make some snippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tbody tr td  {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.me-alone {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="10" style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <span class="me-alone">Some Text</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
      <td>tessssssssssssssssss</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```